# Date and/or time from character string error message

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT communication.*
      ,employeedetails.resourcename
FROM   communication
      ,employeedetails
WHERE  employeedetails.employeenumber = communication.employeenumber
       AND communication.project = employeedetails.projectname
ORDER BY
       CONVERT(DATETIME ,communication.month ,5)
```

I am getting the following error message:

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string"

Kindly help me out

Comment: what is(are) the value(s) in communication.month? At least one of them must be incorrect.

Comment: date time values are there in communication.month

Comment: You should try to better explain how your tables are organized and give some data example

Comment: is it of type datetime or varchar? The type should be datetime but you are probably using varchar

Answer (score -1):

It is not easy having no info regarding the data tables involved!
However if names are meaningful, how can you convert a month to a datetime?
If it is existing try this:

```
SELECT communication.*, employeedetails.resourcename 
FROM communication, employeedetails 
WHERE employeedetails.employeenumber = communication.employeenumber and communication.project = employeedetails.projectname 
ORDER BY communication.day, communication.month, communication.year --due to style 5
```

even if I would suggest to go for style 12

Answer (score -1):

The datatype of communication.month is presumably a character type. If this holds "January" for January etc. then SQL has no way of converting that character to a datetime. You would need to append a string such that SQL could parse it as a datetime.
e.g. `ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime,communication.month + '01 2000',5)`.

However, storing the communication date as a datetime in the first place would be better...